# Nancy proxy requests

Tags: c#, .net, nancy

Is it possible to proxy requests on specific address in Nancy?

For example, when someone make a request on `http://localhost:1234/need-to-proxy`, Nancy should send request to `http://another-server:9000/api` and return response from this server.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to forward all the request data - query string, post data, headers, etc? Its absolutely possible, the question is "why". There's plenty of reverse proxy software out there, which most probably will behave better than whatever you need to write.

If you need to inspect the incoming request, and build a different one for the internal service, then it makes sense to write your own code.

You can create an async route for your incoming request, do async call to the internal service, massage the response (if needed) and return. Calling another server is no different than any other work you would normally do in your route.

Comment: Main reason for implementing proxy in my app is because I can't install reverse proxy software on our customer servers. Also, I think it will be overkill for my task. Actually, I need to forward 1 GET request and 1 POST request to external server.

Comment: @SunnyMilenov can you explain it for non .NET developers please?

Comment: @A.MatíasQuezada: nancy is a .Net framework, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: @SunnyMilenov Non .NET developers can also develop on .NET.
Maybe .NET specialist or experts would be a better word.
In my case I don't see how can I forward for example Request.Query when I can't iterate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get["/"] = parameters =>
    {
        return this.Response.AsRedirect("http://google.com");
    };
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thank you.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!